# How to Print a Message When Temperature is Within a Specific Range in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and working on a program that converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. The program also needs to indicate when the temperature is too high or too low. I've managed the conversion and the high/low checks, but I'm struggling to get the program to print a message when the temperature is within an acceptable range (82-87 degrees Celsius). Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def far_to_cel(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 

celcius=0

#checks that input is an int otherwise they get to try input again
while(True):
      try:
            fahrenheite= int(input ("Skriv in temeraturen i fahrenheite i heltal här tack: ")) 
            break        
      except:
            print("Du måste fylla i heltal, försök igen")
      
#checks if temp is to low or to high
while celcius<82 or celcius>87:
      far_to_cel(fahrenheite)
      celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheite)
      if celcius<82:
            print("Det är tyvärr för kallt att basta")
            break
      elif celcius>87:
            print("Det är tyvärr för varmt för att basta")
            break
```

I cant make my code write out when the temp is ok 82-87, some comments are thing I tried

```
bastu_range= range(82,87)    
#sätter ett värde inom ett spann
#max(87) and  min(82):
#far_to_cel(farenheite)
#float(max(87)) and float (min(82))
#celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheite)
#and celcius!= <82.0 and celcius!= >87.0:
#if its ok temp it will print float and say its ok temp  
if celcius == bastu_range:
      print("Nu är bastun {} grader celcius, nu kan ni basta".format (round(celcius,1)))
      input("Tryck Enter för att avsluta")
```

I'm learning through a distance course and have limited contact with the instructor, so I'm a bit stuck. Can someone help me modify this code to print a message when the temperature is between 82-87 degrees Celsius?

Comment: How can we help you then? What's your question please?

Comment: i cant make my code print out when temp is ok, its just works when its to high or to low

Comment: `celcius == bastu_range` - you probably need `in` here, not `==`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve your goal here and that's when the temperature is within 82 - 87 degrees celsius to do some action, you can modify your loop structure and add an appropriate condition to check for this range.

Which will be like this:

```
def far_to_cel(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 

while True:
    try:
        fahrenheit = int(input("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ")) 
        celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheit)
        break        
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid integer.")

if celcius < 82:
    print("Too cold for sauna.")
elif celcius > 87:
    print("Too hot for sauna.")
else:
    print(f"The sauna is at a perfect temperature: {round(celcius, 1)} degrees Celsius.")
```

For you to actually learn from mistakes here, this is what's changed:
I've modified temperature conversion inside the try block, why? You can now see that it's converted imidietly upon inpu, thaat way it's reducing the unneeded calls to function `far_to_cel()`. Another thing which I did is simplified the logic, code now check if it's either too low or too high (temperature), if it's not it falls back to the else statement block, which simply means the temperature is within 82 - 87 degrees celsius. Therefore, second while loop is as well not needed, since you just need to check temperature upon input.Also, here I am using `elif` and `else` - simply because again, it makes the logic clearer and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate that you took the time to explane to me where I went wrong because I am really trying to learn, but sometimes it hard when u are new and dont have anyone to ask. I usually just try and try myself untill i get it right but wasnt able this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code skip the while loop because of celcius's value is not matching condition range. Example. when your celsius value is 85, your code don't join while loop, and finish code. You can check before if your celsius is in range 82-87, and you can assign mid-point and print to can't tell what the weather will be like.

```
def far_to_cel(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 

celcius=0

checker= True


while checker is True:
    try:
        fahrenheite= int(input ("Skriv in temeraturen i fahrenheite i heltal här tack: ")) 
        celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheite)
        print(celcius)
        if celcius<82 or celcius>87 :
            while True :
                if celcius<82:
                    print("Det är tyvärr för kallt att basta")
                    
                    checker =False
                    break
                elif celcius>87:
                    print("Det är tyvärr för varmt för att basta")
                    checker =False
                    break

        else:
            print("Perfect Time")
    except:
        print("Du måste fylla i heltal, försök igen")
```

But I wouldn't recommend using that code because it doesn't comply with SOLID principles. Because of that, use elif statements. You can follow this code. It will be more clear and more understandable.

```
def far_to_cel(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9   
celcius = 0
while(True):
    try:
        fahrenheite= int(input ("Skriv in temeraturen i fahrenheite i heltal här tack: ")) 
        break        
    except:
        print("Du måste fylla i heltal, försök igen")

celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheite)
if celcius<82:
    print("Det är tyvärr för kallt att basta")
elif celcius>87:
    print("Det är tyvärr för varmt för att basta")
else:
    print("Perfect Time")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop to check the temperature range is inefficient. It's better to use a simple if condition.
The check for the temperature being within the 82-87 degrees range can be done using the >= and <= operators.
Your variable bastu_range is not needed, as you are not using it correctly in the code. It's better to directly check if celcius is within the range.

````
def far_to_cel(temp):
    return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9 

while True:
    try:
        fahrenheit = int(input("Skriv in temeraturen i fahrenheit i heltal här tack: ")) 
        break        
    except:
        print("Du måste fylla i heltal, försök igen")

celcius = far_to_cel(fahrenheit)

if celcius < 82:
    print("Det är tyvärr för kallt att basta")
elif celcius > 87:
    print("Det är tyvärr för varmt för att basta")
else:
    print(f"Nu är bastun {round(celcius, 1)} grader Celsius, nu kan ni basta")
    input("Tryck Enter för att avsluta")```
````